# How do I use the inspector to set PlayerPrefs on button click which will switch scenes?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have two scenes MAP and GAME.

On the MAP, I want to use the variables (in the inspector) on a button to build the level in the GAME.

I have three game modes {1, 2, 3}
I also have a score that needs to be achieved {I want to be able to set this score}

Once the buttons is clicked I want it to save to PlayerPrefs and then in the GAME it will read which PlayerPrefs were saved and then load that data.

Button Script

```
public class LevelButton : MonoBehaviour {

    public float GameScoreNeeded;
    public int GameMode;
}

public void MakeLevel()
{
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("GameMode") = GameMode;
    PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("GameScoreNeedeed") = GameScoreNeeded;
}
```

On the GAME

```
void Start(){
BuildLevel();
}

public void BuildLevel(){
    gameMode = PlayersPrefs.GetInt("GameMode");
    gameScoreNeeded = PlayersPrefs.GetFloat("GameScoreNeeded"); 
}

//Rest of code
```

This is what I think needs to happen, but I can't seem to get the `int` from the inspector to save.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but I can't seem to get the int from the inspector to save.
>
> ```
> PlayerPrefs.SetInt("GameMode") = GameMode;
> PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("GameScoreNeedeed") = GameScoreNeeded;
> ```

You are not using `PlayerPrefs` properly. It takes two parameters. The key and the value. The loading code seems right but the **saving** code is not. Below is the correct way to **save** your values:

```
PlayerPrefs.SetInt("GameMode", GameMode);
PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("GameScoreNeedeed", GameScoreNeeded);
```

It would make sense to call `PlayerPrefs.Save();` after the code above. You can then use `PlayersPrefs.GetInt` or `PlayersPrefs.GetFloat` to read the saved value later on.

Comment: Thanks that is what I needed!